# The answers appear to be in date not vote order

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

Looking at the answers to some old questions this morning, they don't seem to be in vote order.

For example:
{http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-do-i-get-my-6-month-old-to-sleep-better-at-night/4062#4062}

Double-checking, they're appearing for me in date order. I don't remember changing any settings to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question has an accepted answer, this answer will always be at the top. The order of any remaining answers is determined by your choice here: (see red box)

[image]

- **Votes** shows the highest-voted answer first.
- **Oldest** shows the oldest answer first.
- **Active** shows the most recently added (or edited!) answer first.

Comment: Thanks Torben. I thought I had it in votes order. Bit strange.

Comment: An exception are [owner-accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) - they lead to no change in the sort order.